# How to connect to SAP through Salesforce Connect

Tags: lightning-connect, externalobjects, salesforce-connect

Can anyone help me how to connect to External Data i.e, SAP through Salesforce connect using External Data Source and External Objects.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out documentation, trailhead yet and tried anything so far? You will get ample example and guidance on how to do so. You can check this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lightning_connect) to find out more.

Comment: Thank You. Can you please provide some pointers for the documentations. I am confused between what is actually Lightning connect and Salesforce connect.